SharePoint Calculated column displays 1905 as default result
I am trying to calculate the previous year of today by using below formula.
TEXT(Year(Today())-1,"yyyy")

I am using Text() to avoid the extra comma(,) in the output. But the current formula results to 1905 instead of 2023
Please help me if any mistake I am doing here.
Thanks in advance!

try this:
=TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())-1,"0")

It works. Thanks for your quick help
